# User access to an Object

Tags: permissions, user

I am a new salesforce admin and I am assigned with a task to give a user access to an Object so that he can create records. The user profile has Modify all access to the object and can see all the records of that object. But when he tries to create a new record, the system shows up insufficient privileges error. Can you give me suggestions to help this user to create new records for that object.?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you check the role hierarchies?

Comment: The users role is Admin.

Comment: what does the user's `profile` say for the sobject in question - is there Create privileges?

Comment: Do you have record types on the object, and if so does user have access to them?

Answer (score 2):

You state:

> The user profile has Modify all access to the object

This by default **does not** give the user *create* permissions on the object.

Go back to the profile and ensure the user has `Create` checked on their user profile.

In addition, if you are overriding the `New` button on the object, ensure that the user has access to the VF page that the new button is directing the user to.